# Como obtener el valor del DROPDOWN e imprimirlo en el input?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo este `dropdown` pero no se como hacer para que al seleccionar cualquiera me imprima directamente en el `input`.
No lo hago con select porque es como un mini buscador el dropdown

[image: Imagen del dropdown]

Este es mi codigo del input con el `dropdown`

```
<div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text"
                                           class="form-control"
                                           name="codigoOrdenTrabajo"
                                           style="width: 65px"
                                           minlength="5"
                                           maxlength="5">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <button type="button"
                                                class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle"
                                                data-toggle="dropdown"
                                                aria-expanded="false">
                                        </button>
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                            <?php

                                                $item = null;
                                                $valor = null;

                                                $orden = ControladorOrdenTrabajo::ctrMostrarOrdenTrabajo($item, $valor);

                                                foreach ($orden as $value) {

                                                    echo '<a class="dropdown-item"
                                               href="#">' . $value["codigoOrdenTrabajo"] . '</a>';

                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que podes hacer es que al hacer `click` sobre alguno de los `a` del `dropdown` se dispare una funcion, la cual tome el valor del `a` *click-eado* y lo ponga en el `value` del `<input/>`

### Ejemplo:

```js
$('#opcionesCodigoOrdenTrabajo > a').on('click', setDropdownValue);

function setDropdownValue() {
  let $option = $(this); 
  // Buscamos el input donde establecer el valor de la opcion seleccionada
  $option.closest('.input-group').find('input').val($option.text());
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigoOrdenTrabajo" style="width: 65px" minlength="5" maxlength="5">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="opcionesCodigoOrdenTrabajo">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Valor 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Valor 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente Marcos muchas gracias funciono perfectamente

Comment: Ahora el inconveniente es que al usar datatable modo responsive no imprime el value :(

Comment: Intenta suscribiendo la funcion despues de crear el `DataTable`

Comment: Gracias crack se solucionó sin novedad te agradezco

Comment: Marcos me puedes ayudar con una cosita porfavor que no hallo solucion porfavor como te contacto ??

Comment: Crea una nueva pregunta, así entre todos te podemos ayudar.

Comment: Ya la cree Marcos por favor si me puedes ayudar te agradeceria mucho